# Circle method scheduling algorithm for a round robin tournament with an uneven number of teams

Tags: combinatorics

I am creating a software library for creating round robin tournaments where each team plays every other team one time. However, I am struggling with sorting the games for an uneven number of teams.

I implemented the scheduling algorithm found on the [wikipedia page for Round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) referred to as the circle method. Here is an example of how that algorithm works where each column is a "game" if we have a set of teams `1 2 3 4`.

```
1 2
4 3

1 4
3 2

1 3
2 4
```

The `1` is kept in place and the rest of the teams are rotated around n-1 times where n is number of teams.

However, this can not be done with an uneven number of teams as even a simple example such as `1 2 3` fails because it misses 1 match where 2 faces 3.

```
1 2
3

1 3
2
```

Using a simple loop I can generate all the games for any given number of teams. The following is written in Golang but I hope it is easy enough to understand.

```
// teams2 is a copy of teams
teams2 := teams
// I loop through a full set of team
for _, t := range teams {
    // for every iteration we remove the first team in team2
    teams2 = teams2[1:]
    // I loop through the subset of teams which does not include the current team t or any previous team t
    for _, t2 := range teams2 {
        // Here I print the match
        fmt.Printf("%d:%d\n", t, t2)
    }
}
```

That code will give the following output for `1 2 3` which includes all possible combinations.

```
1:2
1:3
2:3
```

However, the problem is that it is not ordered according to the Scheduling algorithm I mentioned earlier. The first game should be `1:3` and not `1:2`. The sorting of games gets even worse with a larger set of teams such as 9 or 11.

**How can I create a scheduling algorithm for an uneven number of teams in a round robin tournament which works as closely as possible to the circle method for an even number of teams?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have an odd number $n$ of players. Add an extra player $n+1$, and apply the circle scheduling algorithm to generate a round robin for $n+1$ players. Whoever plays against player $n+1$ sits still that round.

You get the nicest solution if player $n+1$ is the one that stays at the same spot.

Comment: Thank you, it's so obvious now that you wrote it. I spent days trying to solve this issue.